# Removing a row from a csv based on a string value in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv loaded using pandas of sales data from a car dealership.
One of the columns is titled "Status" and it contain either "Shipped", "In Process" or "Disputed".

I want to remove all of the rows that has "Disputed" or "In Process" from the dataframe.

Currently I have the following written:

for row in df:
if df[:6] == 'Disputed':
df.drop[row:6]
print(df)

I'm sure the problem is the 'Disputed' part but I've tried a bunch of things and nothing worked.